# Can I move my downloaded Origin games to another location without reinstalling them?

Tags: origin

I place all of my games in `c:\games` because I've had times, especially with older games, when the space in Program Files (or the brackets in `Program Files(x86)`) interfered with proper gameplay.

I currently have Mass Effect 1, 2 and 3 and Dragon Age 2 installed through Origin, but I didn't configure the Origin install path properly and now they are located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games`. I reconfigured that path to `c:\games\Origin Games`, but my games are still in the old folder. Can I just copy and paste them into the folder I want them to be in or do I have redownload them?